# What is a blended sauce?

Tags: sauce, thickening

There are three types of sauce, which is 1. roux, 2. blended, and 3. all-in-one. I get what the all-in-one and roux sauce are and what steps to take to achieve it, but what exactly is a blended sauce? My teacher says that blended sauce does not mean blending the sauce using a blender. I searched on the internet and it basically says that is is the combination of a small portion of liquid and starch together, then heat the remaining liquid till it is almost at its boiling point. Afterwards, pour the heated liquid to the blended mixture and stir carefully. Heat the mixture and stir continuously until gelatinisation has reached. However, I came across another definition of the blended sauce: combining two or more sauces together. I'm quite confused, which one is the right one?

Comment: I hadn't heard of that classification before, but it seems to be just for starch based sauces, based on http://www.markrutherford.beds.sch.uk/downloads/Sauces%20-%20yr%209.pdf

Comment: This is how I make gravy: mix flour and cold water, stir well, then whisk into boiling pan-juices-with-water-or-stock-added. It doesn't have to be a super high end technique.

Comment: You say your teacher mentions 'it is not blended with a blender' did you not think to just ask him, what it is?

Answer (score 1):

A blended sauce uses starch suspended in a small amount of cold liquid. This is typically the method used for starches such as cornstarch or arrowroot. The starches blended with the cold liquid, then poured into the hot base and stirred until it thickens.